# JSF h:link rendered span

Tags: jsf

when i use the h:link tag it renders a `<span>` HTML tag instead of `<a>` tag.
Any clues why is this happening ?

Comment: "*it renders a HTML tag instead of tag*"? Did not understand.

Comment: Sorry i forget to use the 'sample code' , thanks for the alert

Comment: "*If the "disabled" attribute is specified, do not render the HTML "a" anchor element or the "href" element. **Instead, render a "span" element.***" I think you should have observed this behaviour.

Comment: Post your h:link, there is more then one reason why it could happen depending on it attributes.

Comment: If an `<h:link>` is disabled, then there is no reason to render a clickable link. (This is the sole purpose of `disabled`). The JSF run-time instead renders a `<span>` tag. The behaviour is documented and implemented. @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: @Tiny I've seen the documentation, but wouldn't a `styleClass` attribute also force a `span` ?

Comment: I already have fix the problem, the outcome was not correct.Thanks guys

Comment: A bare `<h:link styleClass="class_name"/>` renders `<a href="..." class="class_name"></a>`

Comment: For future JSF questions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Therein you're also being recommended to read server logs.